# Making Message-like UI on iPhone (without sending SMS/email)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing a chat app which sends emssages through push notifications and p2p connections (**not** via SMS or e-mail).

I would like to make a view controller which has some custom views at the top and then the messages thread below it. The messages should be presented in a manner similar to `Messages` iPhone app.

Is it possible to reuse Apple code (is there a ViewController / View I can use? Can I somehow use `MFMessageComposeViewController`?) or should I reinvent the wheel and make my own implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several open-source solutions that re-create the messages interface rather accurately:

- [SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/soffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller) by Sam Soffes
- [MessagesTableViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController) by jessesquires

Of course, you could also create the interface yourself by using a UITableView to house custom cells that would draw the speech bubbles, and text inside them.

Comment: Thanks Tristan, that was exactly what I was looking for! I used MessagesTableViewController (better "quick start" doc) and it seems to work perfectly. :)

Comment: Heh, no problem! I ran into a similar issue a couple years back and spent a week trying to re-create the UI... which wasn't my definition of fun. =P

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionViewController could be used to create a messages like UI.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to use my own graphics for speech bubbles and develop text input behaviour from scratch, or can I reuse something Apple did?

Comment: No there is no apple provided class for the speech bubbles and the like. You can find a great tutorial here [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12). You can use any custom UIView for the cells and all the heavy lifting for layout and inserting/removing cells is done for you. (pretty much)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have recently released an open source project that solves this exact problem. The [Chat SDK](https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-ios) is available under the **MIT license** on Github.  The library has the following features that you may find useful:

`BChatViewController.m`

Speech bubble message view similar to the Messages app. Here you can also see examples of how to handle keyboard show and hide events to add the text input box on top of the keyboard.

`BMessageCell.m`

This is the main message bubble class. Here there are functions to dynamically color message bubbles (`+(UIImage *) bubbleWithImage: withColor:`) and to add a speech bubble tail.

`BMessageLayout.m`

Useful utility functions to determine the height for a text area.

`BTextInputView.m`

This a resizable text input box that floats above the keyboard.

The user interface is very modular which means that you should be able to add it to your app relatively easily.

This library also supports [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) out of the box which would mean that you wouldn't need to build your own system to send messages using push notifications.